# Understanding the difference between getSystemService() and getApplicationContext()

Tags: android, api

Take for example to *TextToSpeech* class, whose constructor requires an argument which of type *Context*. My question is, what is the difference between *getSystemService* which requires no other argument than a *STRING CONSTANT* and type-casted, and *getApplicationContext* which you would pass into a class such as *TextToSpeech*?

Comment: They return two different types of objects.

Comment: So does getSystemService return a level of abstraction so that you can interact with a service like AudioManager?

Answer (score 1):

In a word,

- [`getApplicationContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) returns the context of the **current** application running in a dedicated **process**, while
- [`getSystemService(String name)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String)) *"returns the handle to a system-level service by name"*, where the system-level service runs in a **separate process** and the *"handle"* allows invoking methods of the service through the inter process communication (`IPC`).

I hope the difference you're talking about refers to the `Android` security model, which, AFAIK, is divided into 2 categories w.r.t calling the system-level services managed by `servicemanager`:

1. system-level services that can be accessed/used with no specific permission on the app's side / the manifest file (e.g `LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE`, `PackageManager` and others);
2. system-level services that explicitly require a specific permission(*s*) from an application (or its hosting `Linux` process) to be successfully accessed. The permissions are granted by a physical user of device.

Since no specific permissions are required to access the system-level services of the 1st category, the interaction with them can be wrapped with an additional abstraction layer that requires `Context` as parameter to access the services (e.g [`TextToSpeech` API](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.java#TextToSpeech)).